# Encoding/Decoding contract ABI data

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, abi, calldata

How to encode and decode ABI data?

Can someone show me an example with web3js library?

Comment: Are you talking about decoding the input and output of a call to a contract? Oe the contract itself? If the former, why? web3 will provide you with stub methods that let you call contract methods without having to do this yourself.

Answer (score 10):

If the question is about abi params, you can take a look at these two web3.js files:

https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/0.20.7/test/coder.encodeParam.js
https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/0.20.7/test/coder.decodeParam.js

Although these functions are not a part of public `web3.js` interface. Mostly because they need a proper refactor.

There is also a command line tool created especially for encoding function calls and retrieving output data.

https://github.com/ethcore/ethabi

Comment: There is alternative JS tool, which should be ready in couple of days: https://github.com/jacogr/ethabi-js

Comment: Another one: https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi

Answer (score 8):

In case you need an online tool to encode parameters to abi format you can use https://abi.hashex.org/. It has functionality to auto parse contract's abi to get function names and parameter types and provides convenient way to enter their values.

Here is an example of using this service
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I modified web3 npm library by including the following line

```
Web3.SolidityCoder = require('./lib/solidity/coder');
```

after the Web3 object gets created.

In the client side, you can use it with following code.

```
web3 = require('web3'); // This will import the web3 library.

web3.SolidityCoder.encodeParams([types array], [values array])
web3.SolidityCoder.decodeParams([types array], encodedData)
```

This of course is a hack and is suitable for quick testing, if this would be a recommended approach, I could push changes to official web3 library. I'll check with them.

Update: There is a getData() method available in web3.js which you can use for this purpose. Here is the link to documentation:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods

Answer (score 3):

web3 1.0:

```
web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter('address', '0000000000000000000000001829d79cce6aa43d13e67216b355e81a7fffb220')
```

you should receive:
`0x1829D79cCE6aA43D13E67216b355E81A7FfFB220`

you can also try:

https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder

https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use "**abi-decoder**".
I forked the repository and created index.html for easy usage.

You can download and use it from:
https://github.com/Muhammad-Altabba/abi-decoder (you can later check it at https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder once they will accept my pull request)

To download and run using NPM:

```
npm install abi-decoder
bower install abi-decoder
```

Then download https://github.com/Muhammad-Altabba/abi-decoder/index.html to the same directory. Then open the file "index.html" in browser.

You will get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the data for sending a message, a simple way is to encode it like this:

```
contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(cAddr);
payload = contract['transfer'].getData(to, amont);
```

The `payload` is just what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The solidity language docs has the formal explanation:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.24/abi-spec.html#argument-encoding

The TL;DR is that the first 4 bytes are the function signature. Arguments are split into 32 byte chunks, then this is all concatenated together.

For example, take the function

```
function bar(bytes3[2]) public pure {}
```

> If we wanted to call baz with the parameters 69 and true, we would pass 68 bytes total, which can be broken down into:
>
> `0xcdcd77c0`: the Method ID. This is derived as the first 4 bytes of the Keccak hash of the ASCII form of the signature baz(uint32,bool).
>
> `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045`: the first parameter, a uint32 value 69 padded to 32 bytes
>
> `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`: the second parameter - boolean true, padded to 32 bytes
>
> In total:
> `0xcdcd77c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000450000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

For **dynamic arguments**, you encode them as their *location* in the calldata blob. For example:

```
function sam(bytes, bool, uint[]) public pure {}
```

> If we wanted to call sam with the arguments "dave", true and [1,2,3], we would pass 292 bytes total, broken down into:
>
> `0xa5643bf2`: the Method ID. This is derived from the signature sam(bytes,bool,uint256[]). Note that uint is replaced with its canonical representation uint256.
>
> `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060: the location of the data part of the first parameter (dynamic type), measured in bytes from the start of the arguments block. In this case, 0x60.
>
> `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`: the second parameter: boolean true.
>
> `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0`: the location of the data part of the third parameter (dynamic type), measured in bytes. In this case, `0xa0`.
>
> `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004`: the data part of the first argument, it starts with the length of the byte array in elements, in this case, 4.
> `0x6461766500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`: the contents of the first argument: the UTF-8 (equal to ASCII in this case) encoding of "dave", padded on the right to 32 bytes.
>
> `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003`: the data part of the third argument, it starts with the length of the array in elements, in this case, 3.
>
> `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`: the first entry of the third parameter.
>
> `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002`: the second entry of the third parameter.
>
> `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003`: the third entry of the third parameter.
>
> In total:
> `0xa5643bf20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000464617665000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003`