# How to call a contract method using the eth_call JSON-RPC API

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, json-rpc, abi, calldata

Ok, so I'm trying to call a contract method using the methods provided by the Ethereum JSON RPC interface. The JSON RPC is running on an Ubuntu machine. Unfortunately, I can't really get a result back from the test contract I created.

The first thing I did was start Go Ethereum on the Testnet with:

```
geth --rpc --testnet
```

I then open another console and open the JS console with

```
geth attach
```

I then compiled my contract using Browser Solidity, where my code is:

```
 contract test { function double(int a) returns(int) {   return 2*a;   } }
```

Which gives me the following byte code:

```
606060405260728060106000396000f360606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900480636ffa1caa146037576035565b005b604b60048080359060200190919050506061565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b6000816002029050606d565b91905056
```

Then I created the contract with:

```
curl localhost:8545 -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from": "0x8aff0a12f3e8d55cc718d36f84e002c335df2f4a", "data": "606060405260728060106000396000f360606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900480636ffa1caa146037576035565b005b604b60048080359060200190919050506061565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b6000816002029050606d565b91905056"}],"id":1}
```

Which gives me back the transaction hash, which I use to get the contract address:

```
curl localhost:8545 -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionReceipt","params":["0x8290c22bd9b4d61bc57222698799edd7bbc8df5214be44e239a95f679249c59c"],"id":1}'
```

Which gives me back the following:

```
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"transactionHash":"0x8290c22bd9b4d61bc57222698799edd7bbc8df5214be44e239a95f679249c59c","transactionIndex":"0x0","blockNumber":"0xd32da","blockHash":"0xf13f185f0eb1e4797885400e3b371c972eedebcf3eef27815a45b649283ec669","cumulativeGasUsed":"0x14293","gasUsed":"0x14293","contractAddress":"0x5c7687810ce3eae6cda44d0e6c896245cd4f97c6","logs":[]}}
```

I then wanted to call the method "double" with the number "5". The Contract ABI documentation says that you have to take the first 4 bytes of the Keccak hash.
The method signature is

```
double(int)
```

Which gives the hash with web3.sha3("double(int)":

```
6740d36c7d42fba12b8eb3b047193c9761224c267d7a2e96dc50949860652317
```

The first four bytes, prefixed with "0x" are:

```
0x6740d36c
```

The documentation then tells to take the parameter, encode it in hex and pad it left to 32 bytes. Which would be the following, using the number "5":

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
```

In total, the encoded string should look like this:

```
0x6740d36c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
```

So, using this to call the method:

```
 curl localhost:8545 -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"from": "0x8aff0a12f3e8d55cc718d36f84e002c335df2f4a", "to": "0x5c7687810ce3eae6cda44d0e6c896245cd4f97c6", "data": "0x6740d36c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005"}, "latest"],"id":1}'
```

Which gives me this result:

```
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x"}
```

Am I doing something wrong here or forgetting an important step?

Also, are there any way to access already-existing methods within the Go Ethereum library that would free me from having to implement for example methods that to the padding myself?

Thank your very much in advance!

Comment: Did anybody deploy this contract on mainnet so that we can follow along?

Comment: I'm using the JSON RPC via C#. So, I really need to see the equivalent in Json. Is there somewhere where I can see this but with Json?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

## Summary

- Your original contract code would not work correctly until I added a `constant` to the function definition to indicate that this function does not modify the blockchain.
- I had to use the method signature of `double(int256)` instead of `double(int)` to get the `eth_call` JSON-RPC to work.

---

## The Details

### Run Your `geth` Instance

You can use the **Testnet** blockchain that is synchronised with other peers over the Internet, or you can use a private **Dev** blockchain that is only available on your computer and faster to develop with. The `--rpc` parameter will allow you to use `curl` to communicate with your `geth` instance.

#### Testnet Blockchain

You will need to create an account and mine some coins as you need the coins to insert your code into the blockchain or to send transactions to the blockchain:

```
geth --testnet account new
Your new account is locked with a password. Please give a password. Do not forget this password.
Passphrase: 
Repeat Passphrase: 
Address: {aaaa725f2f36a28c01bc47f883534990c9c8bbbb}
```

Your `geth` instance will have to synchronise your Testnet blockchain with other peers on the Internet. This may take and hour or more. Once synchronised, your mining operation will commence and you should mine some coins in 10 or 20 minutes. Start `geth` with the mining parameters:

```
geth --testnet --rpc --mine --minerthreads 1 console
```

To check if you have coins, run the command:

```
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]), "ether");
25
```

If you want to exit from `geth`, press Control-D.

If you want to, you can now run your `geth` instance without the mining parameters as another `geth` instance somewhere on the Internet will mine your transactions. Use the following command to remove the mining option, or just use the previous `geth` command:

```
geth --testnet --rpc console
```

#### Dev Blockchain

You will need to create an account and mine some coins:

```
geth --dev account new
Your new account is locked with a password. Please give a password. Do not forget this password.
Passphrase: 
Repeat Passphrase: 
Address: {cccc725f2f36a28c01bc47f883534990c9c8dddd}
```

Start `geth` with the `--miner` and `--minerthreads` parameters as your `geth` instance will need to mine your private blockchain:

```
geth --dev --rpc --mine --minerthreads 1 console
```

### Flatten Your Code And Assign To A Variable

I had to modify your code to get it to run correctly by adding the word `constant` to your function definition as this function does not modify the blockchain when it is run.

In your example, your code will normally be formatted for easy reading:

```
contract Test { 
    function double(int a) constant returns(int) {
        return 2*a;
    } 
}
```

You can use a service like [Line Break Removal Tool](http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php) to strip out your line breaks, or see [How to load Solidity source file into geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/how-to-load-solidity-source-file-into-geth) for some alternatives.

Your flattened code will look like the example you posted:

```
contract Test { function double(int a) constant returns(int) { return 2*a; } }
```

You will need to assign your code to a string variable:

```
var testSource='contract Test {  function double(int a) constant returns(int) { return 2*a; } }'
```

Note that `//` comments will cause some problems when your code if flattened as all text after the `//` comment will be treated as a comment. Use `/* ... */` instead if you need to add comments to your code.

### Compile Your Code

In your `geth` instance, type in your flattened code with the assignment to the variable. Don't worry about the `undefined` result as this is a normal response from `geth`:

```
> var testSource='contract Test {  function double(int a) constant returns(int) { return 2*a; } }'
undefined
```

Compile your code:

```
> var testCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(testSource);
I0503 09:04:15.907715    3190 solidity.go:114] solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.3.2-0/Release-Linux/g++/Interpreter

path: /usr/bin/solc
undefined
```

If you want to see the binary form of your code:

```
testCompiled
{
  Test: {
    code: "0x6060604052602a8060106000396000f3606060405260e060020a60003504636ffa1caa8114601a575b005b6002600435026060908152602090f3",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}],
      compilerOptions: "--bin --abi --userdoc --devdoc --add-std --optimize -o /tmp/solc497335011",
      compilerVersion: "0.3.2",
      developerDoc: {
        methods: {}
      },
      language: "Solidity",
      languageVersion: "0.3.2",
      source: "contract Test {  function double(int a) constant returns(int) { return 2*a; } }",
      userDoc: {
        methods: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will need the Application Binary Interface (ABI) signature for your contract if you want to access run your function outside this `geth` session:

```
> testCompiled.Test.info.abiDefinition
[{
    constant: true,
    inputs: [{
        name: "a",
        type: "int256"
    }],
    name: "double",
    outputs: [{
        name: "",
        type: "int256"
    }],
    type: "function"
}]
```

**Note**: This is the second hint as to why your JSON RPC call did not work - the method signature has `int256` for the `a` parameter instead of `int`.

### Insert Your Code Into The Blockchain

Run the following commands to insert your code into the blockchain:

```
> var testContract = web3.eth.contract(testCompiled.Test.info.abiDefinition);
undefined
> var test = testContract.new({
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: testCompiled.Test.code, gas: 2000000}, 
    function(e, contract) {
      if (!e) {
        if (!contract.address) {
          console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " +
            contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
          console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
          console.log(contract);
        }
    }
})
I0503 09:09:39.632499    3190 xeth.go:1026] Tx(0x8c15e8b8bb593d4a680b084a455ba82b103e60204638a3674ef1fb90ca0ad4f0) created: 0x7a2d8fa11aa28097135eb514f6a23ba12501191e
Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: 0x8c15e8b8bb593d4a680b084a455ba82b103e60204638a3674ef1fb90ca0ad4f0 waiting to be mined...
undefined
```

Wait up to a few minutes and you will see the following output:

```
I0503 09:10:34.319772    3190 worker.go:569] commit new work on block 11122 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 431.081µs
Contract mined! Address: 0x7a2d8fa11aa28097135eb514f6a23ba12501191e
[object Object]
```

You should save the address if you want to run this contract from outside your `geth` session.

### Use Your Contract Within The Same `geth` Session

Before adding the `constant` to the `double` function, I was getting the following results:

```
> test.double(5)
invalid address
```

**Note**: This is the first hint as to why your JSON RPC call failed.

To use your contract within your `geth` session, AFTER adding `constant` to the `double` function:

```
> test.double(5)
10
> test.double(55)
110
```

### Use Your Contract Using `curl` And JSON-RPC

And now we get to the tricky part.

Your function `double(int)` is really `double(int256)`. From [Solidity - Types](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html):

> int• / uint•: Signed and unsigned integers of various sizes. Keywords uint8 to uint256 in steps of 8 (unsigned of 8 up to 256 bits) and int8 to int256. **uint and int are aliases for uint256 and int256, respectively.**

In `geth`, we run the following command to find the signature of the `double(...)` function:

```
> web3.sha3('double(int256)')
"6ffa1caacdbca40c71e3787a33872771f2864c218eaf6f1b2f862d9323ba1640"
```

And take the first 4 bytest to create the `data` parameter

```
0x6ffa1caa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
```

And using the address from the "Contract mined! parameter", we build the following `curl` command:

```
curl localhost:8545 -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_call", "params":[{"from": "eth.accounts[0]", "to": "0x65da172d668fbaeb1f60e206204c2327400665fd", "data": "0x6ffa1caa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005"}], "id":1}'
```

And run this command from the command line:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ curl localhost:8545 -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_call", "params":[{"from": "eth.accounts[0]", "to": "0x65da172d668fbaeb1f60e206204c2327400665fd", "data": "0x6ffa1caa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005"}], "id":1}'
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a"}
```

The result of `0x0000...000a` is the value `10`.

### Update Oct 18 2016

As documented in [RPC error "invalid or missing value for params" when calling contract constant void functions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9345/calling-contract-constant-void-functions), you may have to add a block parameter to the `params` list. Your command with the block parameter will be:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ curl localhost:8545 -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_call", "params":[{"from": "eth.accounts[0]", "to": "0x65da172d668fbaeb1f60e206204c2327400665fd", "data": "0x6ffa1caa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005"}, "latest"], "id":1}'
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a"}
```

You may also have to leave out the `from` parameter.

References:

- [Ethereum Contract ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI)
- [How does one determine a given method id from a compiled contract?](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3110/how-does-one-determine-a-given-method-id-from-a-compiled-contract)
- [The default block parameter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#the-default-block-parameter)
- [`eth_call`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call)

### Your Other Question

> Also, are there any way to access already-existing methods within the Go Ethereum library that would free me from having to implement for example methods that to the padding myself?

Could you please ask this in another question as this answer is already too long.

Comment: The tricky part was providing the data. I was stuck in getting the `data` for my function for whole day,even after such a great explanation. But `do we really need to do all this for providing data`? I later came across `getData(..)` which did all this for me and didn't need to any of the complicated steps. Just var `callData=myContract.myFunction.getData(parameters)` and I got the `data`.

Comment: Also just FYI the function name is 'double' so that isn't a type within a type.

Answer (score 7):

To use `eth_call`, the tricky part is providing the `data`, which is [ABI](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts) encoding the function you want to invoke and its arguments.

It's essential to use **canonical types**, so `double(int256)` instead of double(int).

```
> web3.sha3('double(int256)').substr(0, 8)
"6ffa1caa"
```

**Padding and [dynamic types](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#use-of-dynamic-types)** must be specified correctly. In this example the `int256` argument of `5` is simply padded:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
```

Concatenating the above gives:

**0x6ffa1caa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005**

which effectively means **`double(5)`**, and specify it as `data`:

> curl localhost:8545 -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0",
>   "method":"eth_call", "params":[{"from": "0xsenderAccount", "to":
>   "0xcontractAddress", "data":
>   "0x6ffa1caa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005"}],
>   "id":1}'

The `to` is the address of the contract being invoked, and `from` is the sender account (usually `eth.accounts[0]`).

---

EDIT: More info on "tricky part is providing the `data`":

web3.js can be set up and [`getData`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) used like:

> var myCallData = myContractInstance.myMethod.getData(param1 [, param2,
>   ...]);

(In this case, may as well consider letting web3.js invoke `myMethod` instead of using `eth_call` JSON-RPC.)

Comment: what if function excepts more than one parameter, like a functions that accepts an address and uint, how to get `data`?

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh Some references http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7675/are-there-any-libraries-tools-for-encoding-input-for-data-field-of-web3-eth-call which leads to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/encoding-decoding-contract-abi-data  EDIT: Saw you found web3.js `getData` in your [comment](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-call-a-contract-method-using-the-eth-call-json-rpc-api/3520#comment9066_3520) which works (but since that involves setting up web3.js, it seems easiest to let web3.js invoke the function too instead of RPC eth_call).

Answer (score 5):

Consider unlocking the account before sending the transaction:

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], 'your password goes here', 9000)
```

or RPC call:

```
curl your_ethereum_node_address:port -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","params": ["your account address","password of your account",null],"id":1}'
```

I was struggling quite some time finding out why the contract was not on the queue.

Comment: See item 3 in [How to reduce the chances of your Ethereum Wallet getting hacked?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/how-to-reduce-the-chances-of-your-ethereum-wallet-getting-hacked/3888#3888). In the older versions of geth at least, your password is stored in your history text file.

Comment: how can i unlock account using private key instead of account password and do transaction  @michail

Comment: `unlockAccount` is deprecated and not work in 2019, instead use private_key and make signature and then send_raw_transaction( or similar method)

Answer (score 0):

eth_call RPC Method[.](https://pngreal.com) Executes a new message call immediately without creating a transaction on the block chain.