# Get smartcontract token balance via JSON RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, dapp-development, json-rpc, tokens

Via Geth commandline I can get my smartcontract token balance with:

```
var mytest = eth.contract([{interface}]).at(contract address);
mytest.balanceOf(eth.accounts[0])
>998
```

I want to present the token balance on my website.  How can I do that?

I tried JSON-RPC and several methods like `eth_getTransactionByHash`, but can't find out how to get the balance.

Comment: Refer to [Get token balance with Ethereum RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49998988/6521116)

Answer (score 2):

**Use [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) to present the balance on your website.**

Geth's console, where you were able to obtain the token balance, is Javascript and uses web3.js under the hood, so your website code will be almost identical.

Otherwise, with JSON-RPC you have to use `eth_call` and you have to [ABI](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/234/42) encode the function you are calling and its parameters.  It is much more complicated, for an example see:
[How to call a contract method using the eth_call JSON-RPC API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3514/42)

---

If server-side rendering is desired, that design decision could be examined because a user should be able to run a decentralized application without a server: Swarm and IPFS are technologies to keep in mind as the direction DApps will likely take.

Comment: Now I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: MyContract.at is not a function. 

With these details: var MyContract = eth.contract([{interface}]). 
And: var tokens = MyContract.at("MyAddress").balanceOf(eth.accounts[0]); 
console.log(tokens);

Comment: Can't spot what's wrong, posting more details in a separate question can help people spot it.

Comment: Use web.eth.contract(interface) and also probably you need to use JSON.parse(abi).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to answer of @eth♦ and comment from @Jeroen

Get Smartcontract **Token balance** with **web3 1.0.0-beta.31**

In 1.0.0-beta... most is handled via **Promises** now, hence you could do:

```
var mytest = new web3.eth.Contract({interface}, '0x123....', {
    from: '0x456...', // default from address
    gasPrice: '20000000000' // default gas price in wei, 20 gwei in this case
});

mytest.methods.balanceOf('0x456...').call()
    .then(function(result){
    //the result holds your Token Balance that you can assign to a var
    var myTokenBalance = result;
    return result;
});
```

- Where `{interface}` is the ABI of your Contract `0x123....`.
- Where `0x123....`    is the address of your Contract.
- Where `0x456....` is the address of your Ethereum Account that holds
  the Tokens (i.e. the ETH account you wish to retrieve its Token Balance from)

Don't forget to add the `new` before `web3.eth.Contract(....)`

@Jeroen That way you won't get the error

> MyContract.at is not a function

anymore.

Note: I am using the **IPC** Provider geth.ipc to interact with my node (as I am on the same PC, localhost, hence more save instead of using HTTP request).

```
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    var net = require('net');
    var web3 = new Web3('/home/yourHomeFolder/.ethereum/geth.ipc', net);
  };
```

Edit: For reference following the ABI JSON ( `web3.eth.Contract({interface}` ) I am using for my smart contract, being `myContractABI` my `{interface}`:

```
    myContractABI = [
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "newSellPrice",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "newBuyPrice",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setPrices",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_spender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "totalSupply",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferFrom",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "decimals",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint8"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "burn",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "sellPrice",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "target",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "mintedAmount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "mintToken",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "burnFrom",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "buyPrice",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "owner",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "symbol",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "buy",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": true,
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "frozenAccount",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_spender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "_extraData",
                "type": "bytes"
            }
        ],
        "name": "approveAndCall",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "allowance",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "sell",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "target",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "freeze",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "name": "freezeAccount",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferOwnership",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "initialSupply",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "tokenName",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "tokenSymbol",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "target",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "frozen",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "name": "FrozenFunds",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Burn",
        "type": "event"
    }
];
```

Comment: I was looking for this answer 2 days ago) sad, that it appeared just 14 hours ago, but it is really **really helpful** answer. Actually, my solution looks 99% exactly like yours.

Comment: how can I get the ABI for {interface}-parameter? I deployed my contract with truffle.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this in C#. Can I see the Json for this? I can't figure it out without seeing what I'm supposed to put in the POST body.

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper I have added JSON of my smart contract - hope that was what you were asking for.

Comment: I need some documentation about how to check which tokens are at an address, and what the balance is. Web3 is not going to help me because I use C#.