# How can I retrieve my account's Augur (REP) token balance via JSON-RPC?

Tags: json-rpc, augur

How can I check the contract balance, like Augur (REP), on an address with JSON-RPC? There doesn't seem to be alot of documentation about this.

Comment: Not a duplicate of the Q&A above. This question is asking about the REP token balance for an address, not the ETH balance.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah Indeed I'm asking for the REP token balance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the REP token balance via JSON-RPC, you will have to use the `eth_call` method. See [How to call a contract method using the eth_call JSON-RPC API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-call-a-contract-method-using-the-eth-call-json-rpc-api/3520#3520) for more details on using `eth_call`.

And from  [augur-core/src/repContract.se](https://github.com/AugurProject/augur-core/blob/develop/src/repContract.se)
, the `balanceOf(...)` function is defined as:

```
def balanceOf(address: address):
    return(self.reporting[address]: uint256)
```

And this matches the [ERC: Token standard #20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20), where the `balanceOf(...)` function should have the signature:

```
function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance)
```

To find the function signature in `geth`, I run the following command:

```
> web3.sha3('balanceOf(address)').substring(0,10)
"0x70a08231"
```

For an example, we will use the REP token balance for the address [0xab11204cfeaccffa63c2d23aef2ea9accdb0a0d5](https://etherscan.io/token/REP?a=0xab11204cfeaccffa63c2d23aef2ea9accdb0a0d5) with the following balance:

[image]

I now have to use the function signature from above with a left zero padded representation of the address to be passed to the `balanceOf(...)` function:

```
0x70a08231000000000000000000000000ab11204cfeaccffa63c2d23aef2ea9accdb0a0d5
```

From [etherscan.io/token/REP](https://etherscan.io/token/REP), the REP contract address is 0x48c80F1f4D53D5951e5D5438B54Cba84f29F32a5.

I ran the following JSON-RPC command against my Parity node (for `geth`, you can leave off the `--header` parameter):

```
curl localhost:8545 -X POST --header 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_call", "params":[{"to": "0x48c80F1f4D53D5951e5D5438B54Cba84f29F32a5", "data": "0x70a08231000000000000000000000000ab11204cfeaccffa63c2d23aef2ea9accdb0a0d5"}], "id":1}'
```

The result from the command above is:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010843f6b148a2ec22c604","id":1}
```

And to confirm the results are correct, I ran the following command in `geth`:

```
> new BigNumber("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010843f6b148a2ec22c604", 16)/1e18
1247958.4593995938
```

You will have to convert the hex result into a number in your application.

### Update Oct 18 2016

As documented in [RPC error "invalid or missing value for params" when calling contract constant void functions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9345/calling-contract-constant-void-functions), you may have to add a block parameter to the `params` list. Your command with the block parameter will be:

```
curl localhost:8545 -X POST --header 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_call", "params":[{"to": "0x48c80F1f4D53D5951e5D5438B54Cba84f29F32a5", "data": "0x70a08231000000000000000000000000ab11204cfeaccffa63c2d23aef2ea9accdb0a0d5"}, "latest"], "id":1}'
```

Reference [The default block parameter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#the-default-block-parameter) and [`eth_call`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call).

`eth_call` without the block parameter worked previously, but now seems to be mandatory.

Comment: Great reply! I'll check if this works tomorrow and when it does I"ll accept your answer.

Comment: As usual, an excellent post from Bokky. The result returned as of today is different, but I guess that is because the owner of that account must have sold or transferred or bought more tokens.