# Trying to swap Eth for Weth (solidity) but always reverting

Tags: solidity

This is my contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

interface ERC20{
  function deposit() external payable;
  function withdraw(uint256 amount) external;
}

contract SwapWeth {
  ERC20 weth;

  constructor(address _weth) public {
    weth = ERC20(_weth);
  }

  function swapEthForWeth() public payable {
    weth.deposit();
    weth.withdraw(msg.value);
  }

  function() external payable {
  }
}
```

Deployment:

```
const weth = artifacts.require("SwapWeth");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  const adrs = '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2';
  deployer.deploy(weth,adrs);
};
```

Lastly I open the truffle console and I input the following commands:

```
let instance = await SwapWeth.deployed()
let result = await instance.swapEthForWeth({from:accounts[1],value:web3.utils.toWei("3.5","ether")})  //accounts[1] is one of the default accounts from truffle/ganache-cli
```

This is the data I receive as error, although I don't think it will help much, it just seems like a revert without any more info:

```
data: {
    '0x725b50b17d0a19117799651852ab816287490d41d6279d4eb7e4a3cecc5a2974': { error: 'revert', program_counter: 318, return: '0x' },
    stack: 'c: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n' +
      '    at Function.c.fromResults (/home/computer/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:4:192416)\n' +
      '    at A.w.processBlock (/home/computer/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:42:50915)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)',
    name: 'c'
  }
```

Apart from the main question, isn't there a way to have the specific error reverted and not just a 'revert' without any other information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert ether to weth you should send the ether to WETH contract

```
weth.deposit{value: msg.value}();
```

The WETH token will be assigned to the contract.

If you call `weth.withdraw(msg.value)` it'll burn the WETH tokens and recover the ethers.

If you want to send WETH tokens to msg.sender you have to transfer them.

```
weth.transfer(msg.sender, msg.value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ismael, I've tried as you said (running only the `.deposit{value}()` line but then when checking `weth.balanceOf(address)` I get 0. You also helped me in my previous question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/100237/balanceofaddress-returns-always-0-balance/100286?noredirect=1#comment124593_100286 and doing it as you say, but I'm constantly getting a balance of 0 WETH at the address I'm passing as argument. Any ideas of what I might be missing? Thanks again.

Comment: Nevermind, solved it! Since I was using `.call()` and not `.delegatecall()` I should have been checking the wETH balance of the contract, but I was checking the balance of the account that sent the ETH through the contract. So I was sending ETH from a EOA account through the contract, and the wETH were being sent TO the contract. Solved!