# web3.personal.signAndSendTransaction as a Contract method?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js

As `web3.personal.signAndSendTransaction` method, Is there any such method available for Contract functions?
for example:

```
MyContract.storeName.signAndSendTransaction("name",
    {from:web3.eth.accounts[0]},"passphrase");
```

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately.

What you have to do is to encode the contract signature and the parameters in the Application Binary Interface (ABI) format, then send this data in the `data` parameter of the `web3.personal.signAndSendTransaction` function.

See the **data** parameter in [JavaScript API - web3.eth.sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction):

> **Parameters**
>
> ```
> Object - The transaction object to send:
> * from: String - The address for the sending account. Uses the web3.eth.defaultAccount property, if not specified.
> * to: String - (optional) The destination address of the message, left undefined for a contract-creation transaction.
> * value: Number|String|BigNumber - (optional) The value transferred for the transaction in Wei, also the endowment if it's a contract-creation transaction.
> * gas: Number|String|BigNumber - (optional, default: To-Be-Determined) The amount of gas to use for the transaction (unused gas is refunded).
> * gasPrice: Number|String|BigNumber - (optional, default: To-Be-Determined) The price of gas for this transaction in wei, defaults to the mean network gas price.
> * data: String - (optional) Either a byte string containing the associated data of the message, or in the case of a contract-creation transaction, the initialisation code.
> * nonce: Number - (optional) Integer of a nonce. This allows to overwrite your own pending transactions that use the same nonce.
> ```

To work out what data to send, check out the step-by-step example under the heading **Use Your Contract Using curl And JSON-RPC** in [How to call a contract method using the eth_call JSON-RPC API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-call-a-contract-method-using-the-eth-call-json-rpc-api/3520#3520), search for "ABI" on this site, and check out [Ethereum Contract ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI).