# Explanation of the most simple contract example needed

Tags: solidity

Here is my simple contract I've wrote in [Remix](http://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.9+commit.364da425.js) and deployed with web3 generated code on my private dev-network.

```
contract test{ function say_hi() returns(string) { return "Hi"; } }
```

When I mined a little and run

> test_sol_test

I get the following output:

```
{
  abi: [{
      constant: false,
      inputs: [],
      name: "say_hi",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      type: "function"
  }],
  address: "0x3dbe4378e0ec4839552d036a46f653d0aee2f2ac",
  transactionHash: "0xc57df09c7ee55c1bb45ee8dbee34cbf26a76e44402d6f4bb6512796b5db17bbc",
  allEvents: function(),
  say_hi: function()
}
```

When I call contract's function:

> test_sol_test.say_hi()

I get the following output:

```
I0304 20:04:56.164980 internal/ethapi/api.go:1143] Tx(0x6d15e04db58c3fee5de1965884ca73420e82bdf45e0b6aed22afe7921f971938) to: 0x3dbe4378e0ec4839552d036a46f653d0aee2f2ac
"0x6d15e04db58c3fee5de1965884ca73420e82bdf45e0b6aed22afe7921f971938"
```

And when I'm trying to get info about transaction:

> eth.getTransaction("0x6d15e04db58c3fee5de1965884ca73420e82bdf45e0b6aed22afe7921f971938")

```
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0xca9f9e8c2f482865c326718d5a33f80f8cc05cc0",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0x6d15e04db58c3fee5de1965884ca73420e82bdf45e0b6aed22afe7921f971938",
  input: "0x37bcda61",
  nonce: 24,
  r: "0x7bc50c0fb7322b4b0d44c15247e3e10d92818131b665ce4c5988de6185723df5",
  s: "0x2ca4763ab0d291e5c66a2be39f2d50b7a5fcc0e86fc4e9a4d2ed42b4ddf3dbf4",
  to: "0x3dbe4378e0ec4839552d036a46f653d0aee2f2ac",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x1b",
  value: 0
}
```

Value is 0, not HEX encoded "Hi".
Where am I wrong? How can I display that message?

Answer (score 1):

at first galance while the `blocknumber` is null that's mean your transaction its pending so you need to mine it. besides, `value` is the value transferred in Wei not your function return.

Comment: Probably I don't understand how transactions works. So how do I 'run' that transaction after it's mined? And see `data` field. Help me please

Comment: i suggest you to read this discussion http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-call-a-contract-method-using-the-eth-call-json-rpc-api

Comment: It works with `const` added to function as described in that link. 
But could you please explain `why` or give me good source to dig into this.

Comment: const function didn't need to send a transaction or spend any gas it is the best to use while the function didn't change any states. so its like if you run it localy (in your client) not in the private chain

Comment: Ok. How can I access `data` field of transaction on blockchain in case if that function in not `const`?