# Ethcore not deploying contract via web3 Javascript API

Tags: contract-invocation, contract-deployment, parity, ethcore

I have written some Solidity code, with a setter method `createId` to write a name-value pair to contract storage, and a getter method `getPermissions` to get the value associated with a particular name. It works correctly in browser-solidity (In screenshot below, `createId` was called before `getPermissions`).[image: (attached screenshot)]

Then, I used the web3 Javascript API from a NodeJS app to send a contract-deploying transaction to a Parity (Ethcore) node, connected to a private chain. That transaction gets mined. Using the JSON RPC API `eth_getTransactionReceipt`, I can get the transaction receipt, which has the contract address. However, when I send a JSON RPC API `eth_getCode` request with the contract address, all I get is: `{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": "0x", "id": 1 }`

To test whether it is just the `eth_getCode` not working correctly, I used the JSON RPC API `eth_call` to call the setter (which has no return value) to set a value, but calling the getter returns an empty result, too. The screenshot shows that the correct value was returned by the getter in browser-solidity.

Is there something I am missing? Thanks a lot for your help.

**EDIT:** Some additional information. I compiled and deployed the following Solidity code:

```
contract test { function double(int a) returns(int) { return 2*a; } }
```

In this case, `eth_getCode` returned the compiled code, given the contract address. Also, I invoked the `double(int)` method twice (with 2 different input values) using `eth_call` JSON RPC API, and got the correct return value in both cases.

Does that mean there is something wrong with the other contract's code (which is more complex than this test contract), **even** though it works correctly in browser-solidity? Are there any known issues in browser-solidity which would cause this? Does this give a hint about what problem in that contract could be?

The Solidity source, which works correctly in browser-solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract owned {
  address owner;
  function owned() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
}

contract mortal is owned {
  function kill() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner);
  }
}

contract IdMgmt is mortal {

  struct acl {
    string dataType;
    string permissions;
  }

  mapping (address => acl) public aclOf;

  function IdMgmt() { }

  function createId(address _user, string _dataType, string _permissions) {
    aclOf[_user].dataType = _dataType;
    aclOf[_user].permissions = _permissions;
  }

  function getPermissions(address _user, string _dataType) constant
    returns (string userPermissions) {

    if (stringsEqual(aclOf[_user].dataType, _dataType)) {
      userPermissions = aclOf[_user].permissions;
    }
    else {
      userPermissions = "NO DATA";
    }
  }

  function stringsEqual(string _a, string _b) internal returns (bool) {
    bytes memory a = bytes(_a);
    bytes memory b = bytes(_b);
    if (a.length != b.length) {
      return false;
    }
    for (uint i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
      if (a[i] != b[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a contract method using the eth\_call JSON-RPC API](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-call-a-contract-method-using-the-eth-call-json-rpc-api)

Comment: Please see my later EDIT. The issue is that `eth_getCode` does not return any code at the contract address. However, when a much simpler contract was deployed, `eth_getCode` **does** return the deployed code. So there is possibly some issue in the contract code, even though the deployment transaction gets mined and receipt shows a contract address. The root cause is not related to `eth_call`

Comment: If you suspect issue in solidity source, why are you not posting the source? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added the code. It was only after I saw `eth_getCode` returning deployed code correctly for a much simpler contract that I thought the problem could be in the Solidity code.

Comment: Now, your question is submitted for re-open will be live soon.

Comment: @niksmac - why does my question still show a banner on top with the message: "This question may already have an answer here: How to ..." ? I thought after I added the code and the question goes live, that message would go away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54957/discussion-between-ajoy-bhatia-and-niksmac).

Comment: @AjoyBhatia please share the contract address and the full command you use to make an `eth_getCode` call. I want to try to reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved. It turned out that the `IdMgmt` contract was not actually deployed due to insufficient gas. The contract was deployed and methods worked when I supplied more gas.

The simpler `test` contract with just one function to return double its integer input needed less gas, so it worked.

Makes sense but it **would** be good if the logs had shown that, but the logs just showed it being successfully mined. Also, in the Parity browser UI, it showed the contract as deployed and address was shown. So everything looked good.