# Solc error invalid opcode, but works in truffle

Tags: solidity, nodejs, ganache, solc, web3js-v0.x

I am trying to compile solidity code in solc(nodejs) but unsuccessful so far.
I have created a sample app for demo.
Here is sample's directory structure (node.js and truffle combined):

```
│   app.js
│   compile.js
│   deploy.js
│   routes.js
│   truffle-config.js
│
├───build
│   └───contracts
│           A.json
│           Migrations.json
│           U.json
│
├───contracts
│       A.sol
│       Migrations.sol
│       U.sol
│
├───migrations
│       1_initial_migration.js
│       2_deploy.js
│
└───test
```

Here is the link to source:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jeBRM_F0PfAqBZy0JWK3gKv53M9mxdcC/view?usp=drivesdk

npm packages:

```
npm i express path fs solc ethereumjs-tx web3-utils web3@0.20.7 morgan
```

It works in truffle both getTotalCount() and add() i.e.,

```
truffle(development)> let a = await A.deployed()
undefined
truffle(development)> a.getTotalCount()
<BN: 0>
truffle(development)> a.add(12)
{ tx:
   '0xfa53d1aac439dbdfea4b004410ebca35275a5f4377b54f64f9ab52388a08e0bf',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash:
      '0xfa53d1aac439dbdfea4b004410ebca35275a5f4377b54f64f9ab52388a08e0bf',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash:
      '0xe743d66e3cb5bf15ac741e9a1efd869249c2eed52ab63f8efc6233b35661fc1b',
     blockNumber: 164,
     from: '0x07df0e5ab4793197007a867d97a3aeeea5347456',
     to: '0x8b421f5c74b48e0f6ae763702754ce172deeb293',
     gasUsed: 47006,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 47006,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: true,
     logsBloom:
      '0x00...//intentional',
     v: '0x1c',
     r:
      '0xd2ac433f565e69e3587d07ebd3fe00a14204add708a47cfbc6406d2c092061f2',
     s:
      '0x7f7f6a80f6d67199b88cc2cde924a0c2c39421aadb29201661891bf03b346219',
     rawLogs: [] },
  logs: [] }
truffle(development)> a.getTotalCount()
<BN: 1>
truffle(development)>
```

but when type localhost:34000/d in postman i get:

```
GET /d 200 4051.218 ms - 12
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at Object.InvalidResponse (D:\assignments\blockchain\assign\assignments\blockchain\src\anarik-4\anarik-v5.0\src_3\anarik-v5.0.2\test\smartContract\solc\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:38:16)
    at D:\assignments\blockchain\assign\assignments\blockchain\src\anarik-4\anarik-v5.0\src_3\anarik-v5.0.2\test\smartContract\solc\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:86:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (D:\assignments\blockchain\assign\assignments\blockchain\src\anarik-4\anarik-v5.0\src_3\anarik-v5.0.2\test\smartContract\solc\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:129:7)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (D:\assignments\blockchain\assign\assignments\blockchain\src\anarik-4\anarik-v5.0\src_3\anarik-v5.0.2\test\smartContract\solc\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (D:\assignments\blockchain\assign\assignments\blockchain\src\anarik-4\anarik-v5.0\src_3\anarik-v5.0.2\test\smartContract\solc\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (D:\assignments\blockchain\assign\assignments\blockchain\src\anarik-4\anarik-v5.0\src_3\anarik-v5.0.2\test\smartContract\solc\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\assignments\blockchain\assign\assignments\blockchain\src\anarik-4\anarik-v5.0\src_3\anarik-v5.0.2\test\smartContract\solc\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) null
_http_outgoing.js:470
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
```

Apps' versions:

```
> truffle version
Truffle v5.0.2 (core: 5.0.2)
Solidity - 0.5.2 (solc-js)
Node v10.14.2
```

solc npm package version:

```
  "_id": "solc@0.5.7",
```

Ganache: v2.0.0-beta.2

Its been days that I am trying to solve this problem but can't.
All methods in my contract give *invalid opcode* error when compiled via solc, but in truffle it seems to work fine, and I can't identify source of the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest first try updating ganache. What do calls do you make when `/d` invoked? What do you do in your contract functions look like? It is better if you reduce your example to the minimal code that causes the error.

Comment: I am suspicious of the `solc` version difference but more suspicious of the postman testing methodology. We can see that it works just fine when the request is well-formed with truffle. While I don't dive into RPC every day it just doesn't seem like a complete message with _a sender_ and a function signature - `localhost:34000/d`. What about the rest of it? Have a look at this for possible hints: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-call-a-contract-method-using-the-eth-call-json-rpc-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New opcodes were introduced in [Constantinople/St. Petersburg](https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/02/22/ethereum-constantinople-st-petersburg-upgrade-announcement/) hard fork.  Solidity compiler was able to produce such opcodes since [0.4.24](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.24), but this feature became enabled by default only in [0.5.5](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.5.5).  Ganache Core supports this opcodes since version [2.5.1](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/releases/tag/v2.5.1), but Ganache 2.0.0-beta.2 [is based on Ganache Core 2.3.3](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/blob/v2.0.0-beta.2/package.json#L191).  That's why you contract failed to work.

Answer (score 0):

After updating Ganache to latest version(v2.0.1) it worked.