# How to explain string serialization when invoking contract method?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, abi, string

On Ropsten testnet I have deployed a contract like this:

```
// creation of contract object
var aContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"lastIdMessage","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"readYourLastMessage","outputs":[{"name":"message","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"idMessage","type":"uint256"}],"name":"readYourMessageById","outputs":[{"name":"message","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"idMessage","type":"uint256"}],"name":"readYourMessageMetadataById","outputs":[{"name":"_idMessage","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_idPrevious","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_timestamp","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_message","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"timestamp","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"messages","outputs":[{"name":"idMessage","type":"uint256"},{"name":"idPrevious","type":"uint256"},{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"},{"name":"from","type":"address"},{"name":"message","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"countMessage","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"whoAmI","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"to","type":"address"},{"name":"message","type":"string"}],"name":"sendMessage","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"payable":false,"type":"fallback"}]);

// initiate contract for an address
var sc = aContract.at('0x59dbff7e055b09f02d5508a7c42f09b4683b2934');
```

This contract has a method I am trying to invoke but first I need to undertand how to encode properly the string parameter:

```
// invoke contract method sendMessage(address,string)
sc.sendMessage.sendTransaction("0xa7e3c7c227c72a60e5a2f9912448fb1c21078769", "Hi Juan, this is marketpay sending first blockchain ever message!", {from:"0xf28dafbfeb41bf32869c9d498da0d651d0206ed4", gas:1000000});
    "0xe1a5d54c5b2ed440d55405ab73516245e909a2e345c734438fc9878801365c56"
    https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0xe1a5d54c5b2ed440d55405ab73516245e909a2e345c734438fc9878801365c56
```

According to this previous transaction I can explore how string data was serialized:

```
// hex header
0x

// 8 chars for method hash
de6f24bb

// 64 chars for first parameter, an account address
000000000000000000000000a7e3c7c227c72a60e5a2f9912448fb1c21078769

// 320 chars for encoding a string
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000414869204a75616e2c2074686973206973206d61726b65747061792073656e64696e6720666972737420626c6f636b636861696e2065766572206d6573736167652100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Well, the question is how can I go from this string:

```
"Hi Juan, this is marketpay sending first blockchain ever message!"
```

to this hex value ? :

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000414869204a75616e2c2074686973206973206d61726b65747061792073656e64696e6720666972737420626c6f636b636861696e2065766572206d6573736167652100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Where can I find a doc explaining string serialization on Ethereum? Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the documentation at [Ethereum Contract ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI)
.

From the [Use of Dynamic Types](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#use-of-dynamic-types) section:

> For the static types uint256 and bytes10, these are directly the values we want to pass, whereas **for the dynamic types uint32[] and bytes, we use the offset in bytes to the start of their data area, measured from the start of the value encoding** (i.e. not counting the first four bytes containing the hash of the function signature).

Here is the breakdown I've worked out so far:

```
// Hex header
0x

// 8 chars for method hash
de6f24bb

// Address
000000000000000000000000a7e3c7c227c72a60e5a2f9912448fb1c21078769

// 0x40 = 64. This is the offset from the beginning of Address
// directly above to the start of the next set of hex strings
// ending with 41 directly below
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040

// 0x41 = 65. This is the length of the dynamic string
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000041

// And this is the string contents. As it is 65 characters, it will
// take up 32 characters + 32 characters + 1 character
// web3.toUtf8("0x4869204a75616e2c2074686973206973206d61726b65747061792073656e6469")
// returns "Hi Juan, this is marketpay sendi"
4869204a75616e2c2074686973206973206d61726b65747061792073656e6469

// web3.toUtf8("6e6720666972737420626c6f636b636861696e2065766572206d657373616765")
// returns "ng first blockchain ever message"
6e6720666972737420626c6f636b636861696e2065766572206d657373616765

// web3.toUtf8("2100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
// returns "!"
2100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

See also:

- The [Example](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#examples).
- [Can you help me parse this input data from a newProposal transaction from The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7606/can-you-help-me-parse-this-input-data-from-a-newproposal-transaction-from-the-da) for use of the `ethabi` tool.
- web3.js - [encodeParams](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/dist/web3.js#L702), [decodeParams](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/dist/web3.js#L834), [test encodeParams](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/test/coder.encodeParam.js), [test decodeParams](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/test/coder.decodeParam.js)

Comment: According to the docs, address is equivalent to uint160. Has that something to do with 0x40 = 64, the offset from the beginning of Address?

Comment: Yup. It's the offset from the beginning of Address to look in the second field.