# How do I execute a transaction with string parameters using JSON-RPC

Tags: json-rpc, string

My contract has a method with this signature:

```
register(byte32 documentHash, string owner, string url)
```

I read this documents (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#function-selector) and tried to execute a transaction using JSON-RPC.

I understand that the **data** parameter for the **eth_sendTransaction** method will begin with "**0x9b74202e**" :  first 4 bytes of Keccak encode from "**register(byte32,string,string)**".

I do not understand how to correctly encode the parameters.

Example:

documentHash = **d46046d56d3807a12978ebccfbf0960790bb8d40f3888ac2d5d8416753cd5c54**

owner = **"johndoe@gmail.com"**

url = **"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96015624/document.pdf"**

For this example, how do I encode the data parameter?

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/deploying-contract-with-constructor-arguments-via-geth-rpc/10863#10863 .

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you want to get the `data` parameter used in `eth_sendTransaction`.

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractABI).at(contractAddress);
var data = contract.register.getData(d46046d56d3807a12978ebccfbf0960790bb8d40f3888ac2d5d8416753cd5c54, "johndoe@gmail.com",  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96015624/document.pdf");
```

This will be your data parameter.