# Why does solidity compiled bytecode not match data for creating transaction?

Tags: solidity, compilation, remix

I'm trying to independently verify the source code of solidity contracts, and stumbled across a case where the compiled bytecode for the source code of the contract does not match the data of the transaction which created the contract. According to https://etherchain.org/account_verify/info and other things I've read, the bytecode received from compiling the contract with the correct solidity version and optimized flag should match the input field of the creating transaction.

The contract can be found here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x9ffa45c5943a0203ee462c48c8b97064abbe28f3#code

Using web3.eth.getTransaction through parity, I see the data of the transaction (0xf991503a9e798e2c8e53c865b09e985f59100a1561f9a5fad546f59e8a4096db) to be:

```
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
```

I'm using the solc-js compiler (with the same solidity version, v0.4.8+commit.60cc1668, optimized), and compiling the same source code shown in the etherscan link gives:

```
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
```

Additionally when I try to compile with the remix online compiler it gives me:

```
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
```

What's strange is that the compiled bytecode for solc-js and remix do not match each other, and also neither matches the on chain contract initialization data. Looking closer at the compiled bytecodes I noticed all start with:

```
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
```

but have different endings after that. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/deploying-contract-with-constructor-arguments-via-geth-rpc . The different endings contains the constructor arguments.

Comment: @johnDA where you able to find solution on this?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29732)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29732)

Answer (score 2):

Verifying the Source code is not easy. You require "exact same compiler version".

See: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/221/852

If you just want to know if a contract exists at the address, the easiest to include a simple function.

```
function contractExists () constant returns (bool result){
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Antonio, I am seeing the exact same problem, I select same remix and same very comp version.. all is good and all identical and it verifies.. BUT when I select optimize in remix and optimize in etherscan verify.. then the bytcodes are very different.   5 line simple state contract, no construct parameters and np libraries

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have checked the following:

- have used same compiler version
- also check optimization runs are exact same (if selected optimization)
- lastly, write your Contract name exactly same as written in source code.

I was also facing the same issue, but in my case I was not entering the correct Contract Name, I was copying from remix at deployed section, which was capitalizing the contract name. Later changing the contract name with exact same name in code, solved the issue