# How to read ethereum transaction imput data without knowing ABI?

Tags: web3js, ether, etherscan

How ot get information about transaction by reading `data` property and `logs` from recipe. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x91bfd54de4f05effe1cede58848ef87b97f334256326ce33d298149b8ce22051

```
const abi = requrie("./abi")
const abiDecoder = require("abi-decoder").addABI(abi)
const web3 = require("web3")

web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x91bfd54de4f05effe1cede58848ef87b97f334256326ce33d298149b8ce22051").then((receipt: any) => {
console.log(abiDecoder.decodeLogs(receipt.logs)); // [undefined] 

web3.eth.getTransaction("0x91bfd54de4f05effe1cede58848ef87b97f334256326ce33d298149b8ce22051").then((trans: any) => {
console.log(abiDecoder.decodeMethod(trans.input)) // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand the values of the `data` property of this transaction you will need to study the serialisation of Solidity data (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#examples) and reverse-engineer the data being passed in this transaction.

Of course even if you managed this without the ABI you will not be able to get any information about the contract (variable names, function signatures etc.).

It might also help to have a look at a question I asked: [Deploying contract with constructor arguments via Geth RPC](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/deploying-contract-with-constructor-arguments-via-geth-rpc) which was accomplishing this process but in the other direction (serialising arguments to be used within the `data` property), although in that example I had access to the ABI.