# deploy a smart contract using multisig wallet

Tags: contract-deployment, multisignature

I would like to be able to use the multisig capability at the time of signing the contract deployment transaction

Is there a tool that allows me to use multisig wallets for the deployment of my smart contracts?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this issue](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9627/deploying-a-contract-from-a-multisig-wallet) helps you, but you can practice multisig wallet or proposals in openZeppline defender [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/admin#multi-signature-wallets) and managing multisig wallet in Openzepplin [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/admin#managing-your-multi-sig-from-defender-admin).