# A tool that does abi.encodePacked to fill data field in eth_call?

Tags: go-ethereum, abi

I'm trying to call a contract's `deposit` method using geth's `eth_call`. This function takes in value `data` in bytes:

```
{
  "from": "0xd9c9cd5f6779558b6e0ed4e6acf6b1947e7fa1f3",
  "to":   "0xebe8efa441b9302a0d7eaecc277c09d20d684540",
  "gas":  "0x1bd7c",
  "data": "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",
}
```

In solidity, I would pass in `abi.encodePacked(arc20Address, assetID, assetAmount, abi.encodeWithSignature("deposit()"))` and it will convert those parameters into bytedata for me.

But since I'm using geth, I was wondering if there's a tool I can use that will do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the contract's ABI you can use [`encodeABI`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-encodeabi).

If you don't have the contract's ABI then you can use [`web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctioncall), or combine some of the other functions from `web3.eth.abi.*`.

If you don't want to use web3js there is [ethereumjs-abi](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi) that implements similar functionality.

But since you are using geth then you have to look at web3 v0.20 documentation, in particular [getData](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/0.20.7/DOCUMENTATION.md#contract-events). Also some of the answers here:  [Encoding/Decoding contract ABI data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/encoding-decoding-contract-abi-data) my help with web3 v0.20.

Comment: I was hoping i didnt have to use web3. But judging from the last link, it seems like i can use https://abi.hashex.org/?

Comment: @doctopus I've used abi.hashex.org in the past, it worked pretty well.